# Linear regression in Octave and R

Tags: r, linear-regression, octave

I am calculating the linear regression of house prices with both Octave and R, with the dataset downloaded from here: https://www.kaggle.com/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction  but I get different results in the calculation of the regression coefficients. Can you please tell me why? Thank you

**Octave :**

```
x = csvread ("kc_house_data.csv")

A = x(:,4:17) #Predictors
y = x(:,3) #To predict
m = length(y);

% Add intercept term to X
A = [ones(m, 1) A];

%Equazione normale
theta=pinv(A'*A)*A'*y

theta =

   4.3372e+06
  -3.6761e+04
   3.4580e+04
   9.2825e+01
  -2.8533e-01
   2.6440e-04
   5.7231e+05
   4.8274e+04
   2.9442e+04
   1.2297e+05
   8.0274e+01
   8.0148e+01
  -2.6189e+03
   2.5843e+01
            0
```

**R :**

```
model <- lm(price ~ bedrooms + bathrooms + sqft_living + sqft_lot + floors + waterfront +view + condition + grade + sqft_above + sqft_basement + yr_built +yr_renovated +zipcode , data = kc_house_data)

summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = price ~ bedrooms + bathrooms + sqft_living + sqft_lot + 
    floors + waterfront + view + condition + grade + sqft_above + 
    sqft_basement + yr_built + yr_renovated + zipcode, data = kc_house_data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1333185  -109929    -9804    89289  4241131 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    9.528e+06  3.089e+06   3.084  0.00204 ** 
bedrooms      -3.891e+04  2.032e+03 -19.154  < 2e-16 ***
bathrooms      4.571e+04  3.496e+03  13.073  < 2e-16 ***
sqft_living    1.720e+02  4.614e+00  37.284  < 2e-16 ***
sqft_lot      -2.589e-01  3.676e-02  -7.042 1.95e-12 ***
floors         2.515e+04  3.810e+03   6.603 4.14e-11 ***
waterfront     5.739e+05  1.867e+04  30.747  < 2e-16 ***
view           4.540e+04  2.265e+03  20.045  < 2e-16 ***
condition      1.844e+04  2.524e+03   7.305 2.86e-13 ***
grade          1.244e+05  2.167e+03  57.428  < 2e-16 ***
sqft_above    -2.445e+00  4.524e+00  -0.541  0.58880    
sqft_basement         NA         NA      NA       NA    
yr_built      -3.596e+03  7.471e+01 -48.134  < 2e-16 ***
yr_renovated   8.375e+00  3.923e+00   2.135  0.03276 *  
zipcode       -3.349e+01  3.099e+01  -1.081  0.27984    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 216500 on 21599 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6523,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6521 
F-statistic:  3117 on 13 and 21599 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: `pinv(A'*A)*A'*y` might not be the best way to solve a linear system of equations. MATLAB has the backslash operator just for this purpose: `x=A\y` solves `A*x=y`.

Comment: there's also the `regress` function, that gives more informative output, like the R model does.

Comment: with regress I still get another theta different from the previous ones: 

theta =

   5.8956e+06
  -2.9378e+04
   4.9147e+04
  -2.9957e+15
  -2.7314e-01
   2.4960e+12
   5.7756e+05
   4.5292e+04
   1.7663e+04
   1.2592e+05
   2.9957e+15
   2.9957e+15
  -3.4028e+03
   1.1336e+01
   0.0000e+00